# UIWebView DOM Selection Object From Coordinate

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, dom

I am using a UIWebView on iPhone to do custom input. I have the event listeners in place, disabled the default touch behavior, set up a custom scheme to message the app, etc; all is working.

The last thing I need to do (I think) is to be able to turn a coordinate into a DOM selection object. I know that, under the default UIWebView behavior, touching the view creates a selection object in the DOM corresponding to the text in the selection rectangle, so somewhere along the way, either in Objective-C or JavaScript, a selection is created from a coordinate.

Can anyone give guidance on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.elementFromPoint(100, 100)
```